# How can I set selection of list view (or stackview) in widget on click?

Tags: java, android, widget

I have a AppWidgetProvider like this, how can I set selection for this stackview on click on "Next event" ?

And please don't care about these lines below, my english too bad to describe more"

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyLiO.jpg)

```
    void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int appWidgetId) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.event_app_widget);
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,ItemWidgetService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,appWidgetId);
        serviceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.stackorlistview,serviceIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManagera = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        appWidgetManagera.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.stackorlistview);
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }

    }
```

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_back"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/title_widget"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Next event"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <StackView
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/item_widget_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:loopViews="true"
        android:id="@+id/stackorlistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `RemoteViews` has the `showNext(int)` method that you would call with the `StackView` ID, and then do `partiallyUpdateAppWidget()`, instead of a regular `updateAppWidget()`. Or are you asking how to set up the click handling, and everything?

Comment: I want every time I click on the textview "@+id/titleview" the stack view will scroll to an item which I want. But how can I setonclick it and which method I call to scroll to ?